# I Can't Connect to my MQTT server via arduino

Tags: mqtt, ubuntu

I have mosquitto MQTT installed on my VPS server which I can subscribe and publish to it using paho client thorugh websockets. However when I tried to connect to it through Arduino, I get the following error:

```
Attempting MQTT connection...failed, rc=-2 try again in 5 seconds
Attempting MQTT connection...failed, rc=-2 try again in 5 seconds
Attempting MQTT connection...failed, rc=-2 try again in 5 seconds
```

I uploaded the following code to arduino:

```js
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>

// Update these with values suitable for your network.

const char* ssid = "IOT";
const char* password = "11112222";
const char* mqtt_server = "burooq.com";

WiFiClient espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient);
unsigned long lastMsg = 0;
#define MSG_BUFFER_SIZE (50)
char msg[MSG_BUFFER_SIZE];
int value = 0;

void setup_wifi() {

  delay(10);
  // We start by connecting to a WiFi network
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  randomSeed(micros());

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
  Serial.print("Message arrived [");
  Serial.print(topic);
  Serial.print("] ");
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    Serial.print((char)payload[i]);
  }
  Serial.println();

  // Switch on the LED if an 1 was received as first character
  if ((char)payload[0] == '1') {
    digitalWrite(BUILTIN_LED, LOW);   // Turn the LED on (Note that LOW is the voltage level
    // but actually the LED is on; this is because
    // it is active low on the ESP-01)
  } else {
    digitalWrite(BUILTIN_LED, HIGH);  // Turn the LED off by making the voltage HIGH
  }

}

void reconnect() {
  // Loop until we're reconnected
  while (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.print("Attempting MQTT connection...");
    // Create a random client ID
    String clientId = "ESP8266Client-";
    clientId += String(random(0xffff), HEX);
    // Attempt to connect
    if (client.connect(clientId.c_str())) {
      Serial.println("connected");
      // Once connected, publish an announcement...
      client.publish("test", "hello world");
      // ... and resubscribe
      client.subscribe("test");
    } else {
      Serial.print("failed, rc=");
      Serial.print(client.state());
      Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");
      // Wait 5 seconds before retrying
      delay(5000);
    }
  }
}

void setup() {
  pinMode(BUILTIN_LED, OUTPUT);     // Initialize the BUILTIN_LED pin as an output
  Serial.begin(115200);
  setup_wifi();
  client.setServer(mqtt_server, 1883);
  client.setCallback(callback);
}

void loop() {

  if (!client.connected()) {
    reconnect();
  }
  client.loop();

  unsigned long now = millis();
  if (now - lastMsg > 2000) {
    lastMsg = now;
    ++value;
    snprintf (msg, MSG_BUFFER_SIZE, "hello world #%ld", value);
    Serial.print("Publish message: ");
    Serial.println(msg);
    client.publish("test", msg);
  }
}
```

i checked my server mosquitto ports which shows

```
mosquitto 10436       mosquitto    4u  IPv4   46043      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:1883 (LISTEN)
```

I checked my conf file and it has

```
listener 1883 localhost
```

so how what's wrong within my code or settings that prevents me from connecting to my server?`

Comment: does it work from other computer then the server?  what is burooq.com?

Comment: @Juraj yes I can connect to using websocket from my computer. for burooq.com it is my server domain

Comment: is 'your' computer other computer then the server computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem:

> mosquitto 10436       mosquitto    4u  IPv4   46043      0t0  TCP
> ***127.0.0.1***:1883 (LISTEN)

Your MQTT server is listening only on port 127.0.0.1.  That will accept ***local*** incoming connections only but nothing from another IP address.

The IP 127.0.0.1 is the LOCAL ONLY IP address.  You need to reconfigure your MQTT server to listen on either IP 0.0.0.0 or whatever that server's actual IP address is.

Check your mosquitto.conf file and look for the line that begins with "bind_address":

```
listener 1883 localhost
```

change this to:

```
listener 1883 0.0.0.0
```

and restart your MQTT server.